# Struct to String - strcat isn't working

Tags: c, string, struct, strcat

I have a struct FRAME:

```
typedef struct frame{
   unsigned char type; 
   unsigned char seq;
   int size; 
   char *payload; 
}FRAME;
```

Than i have an array of FRAMES and i want to concatenate the first one:

```
    frames[0].type='d';
    frames[0].seq=seq;
    frames[0].size=(int)strlen(f);
    frames[0].payload=f;
    //check
    printf("%c\n",frames[0].type);
    printf("%c\n",frames[0].seq);
    printf("%d\n",frames[0].size);
    printf("%s\n",frames[0].payload);

    int num=sizeof(frames[0].type)+sizeof(frames[0].seq)+sizeof(frames[0].size)+strlen(frames[0].payload);
    printf("%d\n",num);
    char *m=malloc(num*sizeof(char));

    strcat(m,frames[0].type);
    strcat(m,frames[0].seq);
    strcat(m, frames[0].size);
    strcat(m, frames[0].payload);
    printf("%s",m);
```

But he gaves me "Segmentation fault in strcat"...
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: `strcat` is for *strings*.  You're passing it a bunch of things that aren't strings.

Comment: i don't understand why people find the question good enough to answer but not to upvote it. if it interested you enough for you to think of a solution then it is good enough for an +1!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`strcat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) function expects the destination to already contain a valid string, which means it should have a terminator character `'\0'`. When you use `malloc` it doesn't initialize the memory allocated at all, its content is *indeterminate* and reading that memory (which `strcat` does to find the terminator) leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

There are also other ***serious*** problems, like you using the structure members *as strings*, which they are not! You simply can't use `strcat` or other similar functions (like `strcpy`). You could use e.g. [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) but then you don't allocate enough memory to store all data in the structure, for example the size of an integer is four bytes, but it can contain *ten* digits (plus possible `'-'` for negative numbers).

---

My proposed solution:

```
size_t size = 1 + 1 + 11 + strlen(frames[i].payload) + 1;
// 1 for type
// 1 for seq
// 11 for the integer (assuming it's 4 bytes)
// strlen(...) for string
// 1 for terminator

char *m = malloc(size);
snprintf(m, size, "%c%c%11.11d%s",
    frames[i].type,
    frames[i].seq,
    frames[i].size,
    frames[i].payload);
```

Comment: So i have two chars (2bytes) + one int (4bytes) and my *payload is variable.. how can i put all together in one string?

Comment: Thank you. It works! But can you explain me why is 11.11 in %d to the integer value?

Answer (score 2):

Problem here:

```
  char *m=malloc(num*sizeof(char));

  strcat(m,frames[0].type);
```

`malloc()` doesn't initialize the allocated memory. So you can't do `strcat()` as there's no 0-terminator (`'\0'`) in `m`.

You can initialize it with:

```
char *m=malloc(num*sizeof(char));
m[0] = 0;
```

You should also check if `malloc()` failed i.e. check if it returns `NULL`.

Comment: I forgot to put it here but i have it in my program.. i edit now.

Comment: @justASimpleUser As said in the answer `strcat()` expects its first argument as a 0 terminated string. So you should either initialize it with `m[0]=0;` or make the first call `strcat()` to `strcpy()`. The key point to note here is that `malloc` does *not* initialize (unlike `calloc`).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the other answers `strcat` requires the source to be a `char *` and that being a valid string.

You are just supplying an `unsigned char` here:

```
strcat(m,frames[0].type);
strcat(m,frames[0].seq);
```

and an `int` here

```
strcat(m,frames[0].size);
```

Is the output binary or a string?

Comment: Is a string. With snprintf works. But now i know i can't use strcat with char's or ints.